# Loop that is using str list to be used as a function

Tags: python, loops, machine-learning

I have list of ML models

```
models = [ 'SVC', 'RandomForestClassifier', 'GradientBoostingClassifier']
```

I am trying to create a loop to loop through all models listed above. Below code works.

```
for i in models:
        clf = SVC()
        
        clf.fit(data_X_train, data_Y_train)

        predictions = clf.predict(data_X_test)  # predictions is an array containing the predicted values (-1 or 1) for the features in data_X_test
        predictions_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(predictions)  # convert array to dataframe

        
        from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

        y_predictions = clf.predict(data_X_test)  # predict y based on x_test
        print("Accuracy Score Employing Machine Learning: " + str(accuracy_score(data_Y_test, y_predictions)))
```

I've tried a few loop methods but they end up erroring like the two below.

The error I am getting is

```
for i in models:
        clf = print(i)()


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-d34dacb41464> in <module>
      1 for i in models:
----> 2         clf = print(i)()
      3 
      4         clf.fit(data_X_train, data_Y_train)
      5 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

OR

```
for i in models:
        clf = i()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-316d0ec4eb4e> in <module>
      1 for i in models:
----> 2         clf = i()
      3 
      4         clf.fit(data_X_train, data_Y_train)
      5 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The issue appears to be because I am using a string in list and this is actually a function.

Why is the string not calling the function? I would assume it would become the function after being called.

Do I need to change my model list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the model instances already, you can just put the variables holding those instances into a list and iterate over them. i.e.:

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
# etc
clfs = [rfc,dtc]
for clf in clfs:
     clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
     # etc
```

Answer (score 1):

`print(i)()` doesn't do anything; `print()` does not return a value at all, let alone a function, no matter what you print. So you're essentially running `None()`, which fails since `None` is not a function.

`i()` would only work if `i` was a function. If `i` is a string that contains code, in order to execute it, you'd have to use `eval()`, like:

```
for code in list_of_strings:
        result = eval(code)
```